# How to activate the error waves in visual studio code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, settings

I recently started using Visual Studio Code for C++ (installed extensions: C++ and Code Runner), and sometimes those red error waves under the code show even though everything is correct, and then the only "quick fix"-option was to deactivate them. I was annoyed by the waves so I deactivated them - and now I do not know how to reactivate them (well, most of the time they actually were helpful)! I found nothing in the settings, even after resetting everything they did not come back.
Could you give me a hint how to activate them again?

Comment: Obvious question, what did you do to deactivate them?

Comment: Well there was a prompt telling me to deactivate them - but there is no prompt asking me whether I wanted to re-activate them! But I found out how to solve that: ctrl + shift + P and then I typed "c/c++: enable error squiggles"

Answer (score 0):

To disable or enable wavy/squiggly underline in visual studio code, [go to file\preferences](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_creating-user-and-workspace-settings)
and change some settings

To disable:

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorError.foreground":   "#00000000",
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#00000000",
        "editorInfo.foreground":    "#00000000"
    }
}
```

to enable: (this color is a suggestion):

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorError.foreground":   "#ff000088",
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#ffe60033",
        "editorInfo.foreground":    "#00ff0088"
    }
}
```